# asp.net mvc static file does not load css/js

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a static file on my asp.net web server using `MVC 5`:

```
wwww.mysite.com/WebViewer/viewer.html
```

When I navigate to this page, I see the page correctly. The page contains references to .css and .js files.

Now I want to render this page inside a razor view (.cshtml).  I am using the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(string path)
        {
            return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
        }
```

and this code in my razor view:

```
@Html.Action("GetHtmlPage","Home", new { path = "~/WebViewer/viewer.html" });
```

My page renders and the static file renders, but the css and/or .js files are not rendering properly.  I'm not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: can u post the css link's tag plz?

Comment: The references are like this...

<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

All resources are contained inside the WebViewer, in a hierarchy structure that the page uses. 



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/themes/classic/icons.css">

Comment: little piece of advice: open the page with firefox, select tools>web developer>inspector, find the css tag and edit its href until u get it right.

Comment: I've been trying that for the last hour or two :)

Comment: What is the url you are using to access your MVC page?  Not the GetHtmlPage URL, the page for your Razor.  Are you using the default Url?  Remember, browsers seek relative url's based on current URL, so if your main page's URL is / then it's trying to do ../resources/... and can't find it because .. doesn't exist, you're already at the root.

Comment: try accessing the css file with a href like "/WebViewer/..." and avoid using an href that starts with "../" css path better not be relative. put multiple copies in different levels of the directory structure and find out where you can load it.